# About MemoryError

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I am using [popgen](https://www.mobilityanalytics.org/popgen.html#Software) 2.0 which is a python based population synthesizer.

I was getting memory error with 8 GB RAM. I increased it to 12 GB. I am still getting memory error. Is there any way to determine how much RAM do I need to run without memory error?

Comment: I do not know how popgen works, however can't you set the size of whatever you create, and start with small size to assess the impact on the RAM?

Comment: I tried. This problem I am facing with a larger county. I tried with smaller county it worked. But the problem is, one synthesizer run for 7-15 days. So, it's tough to do the trial and error.

Comment: That's long... Sadly I doubt there is any other way :/ If you have some contacts, try to "borrow" or to use the workstation of someone.